# Cas not working on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cas

I am trying to configure CAS 3.4.11 on tomcat 6.0.35 for SSO login that I want to implement in my grails app. I have changed the authenticationHandlers to following:

```
<property name="authenticationHandlers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler"
                  p:httpClient-ref="httpClient" />
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler">
                <property name="passwordEncoder" ref ="passwordEncoder" />
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="sql" value=" select user_password from user where lower(user_name) = lower(?) " />
            </bean>
        </list>
</property>
```

and password encoder to:

```
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.DefaultPasswordEncoder">
 <constructor-arg index="0" value="MD5" />
</bean>
```

But when i start the tomcat server, I get an error on password encoder part.
I get an error as follows "cannot create inner bean org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.DefaultPasswordEncoder"
I am very confused, any help at this point will be very much appreciated.

---

Here is the log & 
Thanks for the response

`2012-04-25 14:38:58,615 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Loaded 4 services.
2012-04-25 14:38:58,748 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener] - SafeContextLoaderListener: 
The Spring ContextLoaderListener we wrap threw on contextInitialized.
But for our having caught this error, the web application context would not have initialized.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#111bfbc' of type [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] while setting bean property 'authenticationHandlers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] for bean with name 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#111bfbc' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody0(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:62)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized_aroundBody1$advice(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SafeContextLoaderListener.java:1)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#111bfbc' of type [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] while setting bean property 'authenticationHandlers' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] for bean with name 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#111bfbc' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] for bean with name 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#111bfbc' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:433)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
    ... 56 more`

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for your error?

Comment: Could you please post the entire debug output in the catalina log file? There's not enough info in your post to determine the exact cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot find class [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler] for bean with name 'org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler#111bfbc' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml];

means it can't find the jar for the jdbc classes in the WEB-INF/lib. specifically cas-server-support-jdbc-VERSION.jar and/or its 2 dependencies.

Assuming you deployed it via Maven as recommended by CAS/jasig:

Best practice is to add this to the pom.xml in the source and redeploy it. (you should compare and copy back any changes in the deployerConfigContext and spring-configuration to the source before you rebuild.)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
  <artifactId>cas-server-support-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise you'll be tracking down dependencies and resolving version compatibilities for hours.

if you didn't deploy it via WAR/Maven, start looking for a cas-server-support-jdbc-x.y.z.jar to support your server and install it in web-inf/lib, restart tomcat and see what the next dependency is.

Comment: the key is to look for the last nested exception before it starts into (

org.springframework . etc w/ *.java:xxx

) as that is actually a separate stack trace.